# Discord.js bot keeps getting random errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so I'm running my bot by typing "node ." in the console and it runs like normal, but after some random time it gives me this error: 
It's run on node.js and the bot works fine normally until the error randomly shows. Like I said, it just randomly happens, if tried to find a correlation with commands run in my server and the error showing up, but nothing seems to show. I start my bot as follows:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
client.login("myTokenGoesHere");
```

the error:

```
ErrorEvent {
  target:
   WebSocket {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        message: [Function],
        open: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     readyState: 2,
     protocol: '',
     _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
     _finalize: [Function: bound finalize],
     _closeFrameReceived: false,
     _closeFrameSent: false,
     _closeMessage: '',
     _closeTimer: null,
     _finalized: true,
     _closeCode: 1006,
     _extensions: {},
     _isServer: false,
     _receiver:
      Receiver {
        _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
        _extensions: null,
        _maxPayload: 0,
        _bufferedBytes: 0,
        _buffers: null,
        _compressed: false,
        _payloadLength: 393,
        _fragmented: 0,
        _masked: false,
        _fin: true,
        _mask: null,
        _opcode: 1,
        _totalPayloadLength: 0,
        _messageLength: 0,
        _fragments: null,
        _cleanupCallback: null,
        _isCleaningUp: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _loop: false,
        add: [Function: bound add],
        onmessage: null,
        onclose: null,
        onerror: null,
        onping: null,
        onpong: null,
        _state: 0 },
     _sender:
      Sender {
        _extensions: {},
        _socket: [TLSSocket],
        _firstFragment: true,
        _compress: false,
        _bufferedBytes: 0,
        _deflating: false,
        _queue: [] },
     _socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'gateway.discord.gg',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'gateway.discord.gg',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        timeout: 0,
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 29,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 19058858,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 19205,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     _error: null,
     url: 'wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json',
     _req: null },
  type: 'error',
  message: 'read ECONNRESET',
  error:
   { Error: read ECONNRESET
       at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } }
```

Comment: Can you give us anymore details? For example the code that deploys the bot with configuration or if the bot is from a library or company what library/company is the bot from?

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying to help, not exactly sure what you mean but it's run on node.js and the bot works fine normally until the error randomly shows. 

I start my bot as follows: 
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login("myTokenGoesHere");

Comment: It's probably better if you include additional information like this in the question post itself, so it is easier to see and understand :)

Answer (score 0):

If you loon at the error it says:
`message: 'read ECONNRESET',`
This means that the Connection reset this could because of:

- Your Internet having issues/lag
- Issues at Cloudflares/Discords Servers
- Your OS put itself into Sleepmode and cut the connection

If your bot crashes because of it add:

```js
client.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error);
    // Do something eg. Log the Error
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you for answering, is there a way to automatically insert "node ." in the terminal if this happens? Can't be my internet since it's 250 mbps+ and my OS is on all the time.

Comment: You could use something like pm2 its a process managee wich restarts xour bot automatically

Comment: Yeah I tried installing that but dont know how it works